# Catestrophic Forgetting in multiobjective DQN

Tags: pytorch, reinforcement-learning, agent

I am trying to code up a SER multi-objective version of DQN in Pytorch.

However I am having big problems with catestrophic forgetting.  The agent learns optimally for the first 400 episodes and then proceeds to achieve terrible results.

I have played around with hyperparameters and havn't seen any improvement.

Interestingly when I viewed the frames from the episode the Agent takes the submarine to the empty square to the right of the highest reward (or nearby it) but never actually drops into the treasure.

When the preference weight for treasure is low (>.5) the agent finds the optimal behaviour, but when the emphasis is on treasure it converges to this strange behaviour.  Any help would be appreciated

```
### start with a fixed weight!
# t_weight=0.01,  r_weight=0.99

import mo_gymnasium as mo_gym
import gymnasium as gym
import math
import random
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from collections import namedtuple, deque
from itertools import count
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.optim as optim
import torch.nn.functional as F
import numpy as np


pref_weight=np.array([0.99,0.01])


env = mo_gym.make("deep-sea-treasure-v0")
device = torch.device("cuda" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")
Transition = namedtuple('Transition',
                        ('state', 'action', 'next_state', "epdone",'reward'))

class ReplayMemory(object):
    def __init__(self, capacity):
        self.memory = deque([], maxlen=capacity)
    def push(self, *args):
        """Save a transition"""
        self.memory.append(Transition(*args))
    def sample(self, batch_size):
        return random.sample(self.memory, batch_size)
    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.memory)



### first big change.... make the output of the network a BxAxObj tensor
##    to do in v2... concat the input with the weight preference vector
class DQN(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, n_observations, n_actions,n_objectives):
        super(DQN, self).__init__()
        self.layer1 = nn.Linear(n_observations, 128)
        self.layer2 = nn.Linear(128, 128)
        self.layer3 = nn.Linear(128, n_actions*n_objectives)
    def forward(self, x):
        x = F.relu(self.layer1(x))
        x = F.relu(self.layer2(x))
        x= self.layer3(x)
        batch_size=x.shape[0]
        x = x.view(batch_size,n_actions,n_objectives)
        return x



def plot_durations(show_result=False):
    plt.figure(1)
    durations_t = torch.tensor(episode_scalar_reward, dtype=torch.float)
    if show_result:
        plt.title('Result')
    else:
        plt.clf()   #clears the current plot, but leaves the plotting window open
        plt.title('Training...')
    plt.xlabel('Episode')
    plt.ylabel('Duration')
    plt.ylim(-1,30)
    plt.plot(durations_t.numpy())
    # Take 100 episode averages and plot them too
    if len(durations_t) >= 100:
        means = durations_t.unfold(0, 100, 1).mean(1).view(-1)
        means = torch.cat((torch.zeros(99), means))
        plt.plot(means.numpy())

    plt.pause(0.001)  # pause a bit so that plots are updated

BATCH_SIZE = 128
GAMMA = 0.99
EPS_START = 0.9
EPS_END = 0.3 #0.05
EPS_DECAY = 500
TAU = 0.005
LR = 6e-4

n_actions = env.action_space.n
n_objectives = env.observation_space.shape[0]
state, info = env.reset()
n_observations = len(state)

policy_net = DQN(n_observations, n_actions,n_objectives).to(device)
target_net = DQN(n_observations, n_actions,n_objectives).to(device)
target_net.load_state_dict(policy_net.state_dict())

optimizer = optim.AdamW(policy_net.parameters(), lr=LR, amsgrad=True)
criterion = nn.SmoothL1Loss()  #nn.MSELoss()
memory = ReplayMemory(10000)  #was set to 1mill
steps_done = 0
episode_scalar_reward = []


num_episodes=2000
for i_episode in range(num_episodes):
    env = mo_gym.make("deep-sea-treasure-v0")
    state, info = env.reset()
    state = torch.tensor(state, dtype=torch.float32, device=device).unsqueeze(0)
    scalar_reward=0
    for t in count():
        sample=random.random()
        eps_threshold = EPS_END+(EPS_START-EPS_END)*math.exp(-1.*steps_done/EPS_DECAY)
        steps_done+=1

        if sample>eps_threshold:
            with torch.no_grad():
                action_obj_values = policy_net(state)[0]  #will be a AxObj tensor  got rid of the B here
                greedy_action=0
                greedy_scalar_action_value=-1000000
                for i in range(n_actions):
                    scalar_action_value=torch.dot(action_obj_values[i],torch.tensor(pref_weight,dtype=torch.float32,device=device)).item()
                    if scalar_action_value> greedy_scalar_action_value:
                        greedy_scalar_action_value=scalar_action_value
                        greedy_action=i
                action=torch.tensor([[greedy_action]],device=device,dtype=torch.int64)

        else:
            action= torch.tensor([[env.action_space.sample()]],device=device,dtype=torch.int64)

        observation, reward, terminated, truncated, _ = env.step(action.item())
        scalar_reward+=np.dot(reward,pref_weight)
        reward = torch.tensor([reward], device=device)
        done = terminated or truncated
        next_state=torch.tensor(observation, dtype=torch.float32, device=device).unsqueeze(0)
        epdone = torch.tensor([done],device=device, dtype=torch.bool)

        memory.push(state, action, next_state,epdone, reward)
        state = next_state


        #### this is where is gets messy... reward will be a vector now
        if len(memory)>BATCH_SIZE:
            transitions=memory.sample(BATCH_SIZE)
            batch=Transition(*zip(*transitions))
            state_batch = torch.cat(batch.state)     ###  [128,2]
            action_batch = torch.cat(batch.action)
            reward_batch = torch.cat(batch.reward)     ### [128,2]
            next_state_batch = torch.cat(batch.next_state)
            epdone_batch=torch.cat(batch.epdone)
            epdone_batch=~epdone_batch.unsqueeze(1)






            ################# change this to finding the next state greedy action
            state_action_values = policy_net(state_batch) ## BxAxObj  #find current values for state and chosen action
            chosen_current_values = state_action_values[torch.arange(state_action_values.size(0)), action_batch.squeeze()]   ####this returns a BxObj tensor


            my_next_state_greedy_action_values = target_net(next_state_batch) #BxAxOb   #find state values for whichever action is max in ns
            greedy_next_actions=[]
            for batch in my_next_state_greedy_action_values:
                greedy_action=0
                greedy_action_value=-100
                for row_index in range(batch.shape[0]):
                    sl_value=torch.dot(batch[row_index],torch.tensor(pref_weight,dtype=torch.float32))
                    if sl_value >greedy_action_value:
                        greedy_action=row_index
                        greedy_action_value= sl_value
                greedy_next_actions.append(greedy_action)

            greedy_next_actions=torch.tensor(greedy_next_actions).view(-1,1)
            #print("before my_next_state_greedy_action_values shape",my_next_state_greedy_action_values.shape)

            next_state_values = my_next_state_greedy_action_values[torch.arange(my_next_state_greedy_action_values.size(0)),greedy_next_actions.squeeze()]
            # calc  r+gamma*(Q(s',a*)


###############################   examine this part!!!!   ##############################################
            #print("shape of ep_done batch",epdone_batch.shape)
            #print("shape of my_next_state_greedy_action_values",next_state_values.shape)
            #print("reward_batch shape",reward_batch.view(128,-1).shape)
            my_expected_next_state_values = epdone_batch * (GAMMA * next_state_values) + reward_batch.view(128,-1)

            chosen_current_values=chosen_current_values.view(-1)
            my_expected_next_state_values=my_expected_next_state_values.view(-1)
            loss = criterion(chosen_current_values,my_expected_next_state_values)
            ######################################################################

            optimizer.zero_grad()
            loss.backward()
            #torch.nn.utils.clip_grad_value_(policy_net.parameters(), 100)         #####  turned grad clipping off
            optimizer.step()
        target_net_state_dict = target_net.state_dict()
        policy_net_state_dict = policy_net.state_dict()

        ##### soft update code
        #for key in policy_net_state_dict:
         #   target_net_state_dict[key] = policy_net_state_dict[key]*TAU \
          #                               + target_net_state_dict[key]*(1-TAU)
        ### hard update target
        if i_episode %50 ==0:
            target_net.load_state_dict(policy_net_state_dict)
        if done:   #when the episode is finally done append the scalar reward to the list for plotting
            episode_scalar_reward.append(scalar_reward)
            #plot_durations()
            break
    if i_episode%50==0:
        frames=[]
        env = mo_gym.make("deep-sea-treasure-v0", render_mode="rgb_array")
        state,_= env.reset()
        ep_done=False
        total_return = 0.
        state = torch.tensor(state,dtype=torch.float32,device=device).unsqueeze(0)
        while not ep_done:
            with torch.no_grad():
                    ######## change this to finding the greedy action in tensor
                action_obj_values=policy_net(state)[0]
                greedy_action = 0
                greedy_scalar_action_value = -1000000
                for i in range(n_actions):
                    scalar_action_value = torch.dot(action_obj_values[i], torch.tensor(pref_weight, dtype=torch.float32,
                                                                                       device=device)).item()
                    if scalar_action_value > greedy_scalar_action_value:
                        greedy_scalar_action_value = scalar_action_value
                        greedy_action = i
                action = torch.tensor([[greedy_action]], device=device, dtype=torch.int64)

            next_state,reward,terminated,truncated,_=env.step(action)
            frame=env.render()
            plt.imshow(frame)
            plt.show(block=False)  # Display the frame without blocking
            plt.pause(0.05)
            plt.close()

            next_state = torch.tensor(next_state,dtype=torch.float32,device=device).unsqueeze(0)

            total_return+=np.dot(reward,pref_weight)
            state=next_state
            ep_done=terminated or truncated
        print("\n_______________________\n episode:",i_episode,"\nscalarised reward:" ,total_return,"\n_______________________")



print('Complete')
#plot_durations(show_result=True)
#plt.ioff()
#plt.show()
```